# How to implement dynamic tabs in Angularjs 2 with recursion directives/component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs

How to implement dynamic tabs in Angularjs 2 with recursion directives/component.

```
<tabs>
      <tab tabTitle="Tab 1">
        Here's some content.
          <subtab> Sample sub</subtab>
          <subtab> Sample sub</subtab>
      </tab>
      <tab tabTitle="Tab 2">
        And here's more in another tab.
          <subtab> Sample sub
              <subsubtab> Sample sub sub</subsubtab>
          </subtab>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
```

Recalling the selector in same component, but it is not working.
Is it possible to implement dynamically in angularJS 2.

```
@Component({
    selector:'tabs'
})
@View({
    templateUrl: `
     <li> tabs 
         <tabs></tabs> 
    </li>
`
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?  It's not clear you need a recursive directive.  If you're just trying to loop through some tab objects in your controller and show them and their subtabs, something like this should get you there:

```
<tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
    <subtab ng-repeat="subtab in tab.subtabs">
```

Comment: Thank you,  Actually i'm looking dynamic looping.

Comment: [{
      tab: '',
      subtab: {
             tab:'',
             tab1:'',
          },
      subtab1:''
           
    },
    {
      tab: '',
      subtab: {
             tab:'',
             tab1:'',
          },
      subtab1:'',
      subtab2: {
             tab:{
               subtab:'',
               subtab1:''
             }
             tab1:''
          },
           
    }]

Actually i'm looking dynamic looping/recursive directive ie: directive inside same directive in angularJS 2

Comment: Got it.  I'll have to come back and add some code later but what you can do if you have an arbitrarily nested structure is to check if there are children to loop through in your directive's link function and append them -- this gives a good example: http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/06/24/nested-recursive-directives-in-angular/ which should be helpful

Comment: I tried this http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/06/24/nested-recursive-directives-in-angular/, but it is not supporting in AngularJS 2.

Comment: @Component({
    selector:'tabs'
})
@View({
    templateUrl: `
     <ul> tabs 
         <li *ngIf="tab in tabsList"><tabs [list]="tab"></tabs></li> 
    </ul>
`
})

export class TabsComp Implement ngInit{
 @Input list;
 private tabsList;
 
 ngInit{
  this.tabsList = this.list;
 }
 
}.  It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
[{
  tab: '',
  subtab: {
         tab:'',
         tab1:'',
      },
  subtab1:''

},
{
  tab: '',
  subtab: {
         tab:'',
         tab1:'',
      },
  subtab1:'',
  subtab2: {
         tab:{
           subtab:'',
           subtab1:''
         }
         tab1:''
      },

}]
```

Actually i'm looking dynamic looping/recursive directive ie: directive inside same directive in angularJS 2